# Two equal functions giving different results

Tags: javascript

I have two functions that check whether an array is sorted. The first function seems to be accurate most of the time but not always, the second one seems to be working the way it's supposed to 100% of the time. The conditional statements are the same, so I'm wondering what is causing this difference in behavior?

```js
function test(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 0) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}

console.log(test([2, 20, 1]))

function test2(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(test2([2, 20, 1]))
```

Comment: The first version returns either `true` or `false` on the first iteration, it doesn't go through the entire array. The second version doesn't return `true` until the loop ends.

Comment: What makes you think that these two functions are equal?

Comment: Both of them have another bug: On the last iteration, `arr[i+1]` will access outside the array. The iteration condition should be `i < arr.length-1`

Comment: @Nico Haase can you explain the difference in the format? I thought the second one just used shorter code omitting extra brackets

Comment: Your intention would be clearer if you wrote: `if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this code is that you are returning a value on the first check the loop. In the first code example, it will test:

```
if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 0) {
  return false
} else {
  return true
}
```

whether or not the condition is met, your code is returning something on the very first loop. Remember that when a function returns something, it is immediately ended and will not return any other values.

In the second function every time it goes through the loop it will ONLY return false if there the condition isn't met, if the condition is met it will just continue. It will return true at the very end AFTER the entire loop finishes.

Comment: Where can i read about this type of If statements? It's the first time i encountered them and i can't find any documentation about them

Comment: @Qaqli The same type of if statements are being used, its just in the first function you also use an else statement too.

Comment: but the second function also has two return statements? Both false and true